# Appmaker - How to enforce validation for suggest box when value is not selected from the options?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have a form which contains a suggest box. When I click on submit one of the requirement is to not submit the form if the value is not selected from the options.

The problem occurs when we select a value and then clear it and then enter a text not chosen from the options. (Scenario quite possible as some users may not know that value is only to be chosen from the options etc)
In this case the value is still the old one and so the validation does not show any error thus creating an illusion for the user that the text which he entered is accepted as the value.

How do we restrict this?

Comment: Don't use a suggestbox, as the name suggests, it just suggests and not enforce anything. Why not use a dropdown instead?

Comment: There are a lot of names i.e more than 500 atleast and will keep increasing with time. With a dropdown it can be tedious for the user to search in that. The reason I chose suggest box is that it allows the user to type first few alphabets and then shows the appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Can you explain this `In this case the value is still the old one and so the validation does not show any error` a bit more? screenshots if possible? How exactly do you recognize that the value is the old one then?

Comment: In  suggest box if you enter a text but do not choose anything from the options the value does not change. 

Eg To visualize

Step1: I chose a value lets say "John" from the options.
 Now the value is John.

Step2: I clear the widget and just enter a random text, not choosing anything from the options.
The value will still be "John".

The validation will not show any error because:
My validation is just to check if the value exists in the list

Comment: Have you tried validating with `onValueChange()` or `Edit`?  Something like ``if(options.indexOf(newValue) === -1){alert('Incorrect value. Choose from options')}``

Comment: Thanks so much!!   I had forgotten that something like newValue also exists.
I added widget.value=newValue in OnValueEdit event and now the validation works.